# Confusion in using Auto update stat async

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER DATABASE COND_OBSERV SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON
```

I’m seeing random time outs every so many days and I wonder if  it is an auto update statistics issue.  I’m still trying to track that down to see what might be happening.
Is there any harm, outside of the query optimizer using the last plan and then kicking off a thread to update status for the next query, in turning this on?
Any large downsides?

I have this option enabled on my local and don’t see any issues.

Comment: SQL Server and PL/SQL Developer? Very odd combination...

Comment: I think you are right..I editied and removed PL/SQL Developer